# IDE crashes daily - is it Ubuntu , is it Android-studio or something else?

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-12.04

--EDIT-- following @siva advice, i switched over to Oracle JDK from OpenJDK.

also updated a bunch of recently added stuff in the SDK 'manager'...

--END EDIT --

At random, UI event in the IDE like ( open edit on android proj file ) results in very long UI freeze then app crash.

Env:
  Android studio 1.0 Prod
  Ubuntu 12.04 - 3.8.13-03081328-generic

Random crashes ( daily in Android-studio IDE ) that produce large , 'apport' crash dump in :

```
-rw-r----- 1 rob      whoopsie 177030197 Dec  9 20:14 _usr_lib_jvm_java-7-openjdk-amd64_jre_bin_java.1000.crash
```

NOTE - im still using the 'openJDK' with AS despite the warning in AS about issues with JVM's other than oracle. Maybe , after all this time on ubuntu/OpenjavaJSK , i need to switch JVM's
.

Ubuntu reports a crash dialog error in a pop-up box  similar to [this one](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62501)

Pretty sure the abend is within a shared lib in folder:

```
 /home/user/.AndroidStudio/system/tmp/native-platform-nnn-dir/libnative-platform.so
```

Where to report this?

ubuntu apport crash dump

OR

Android-studio forums

IMO - its within a shared lib installed by the app ( AS ) but i dont see anything in the Android-studio forum space mentioning this type of crash??

PS - what are all these Shared libs under /home/user/.Androidstudio/system/tmp

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 rob rob  4096 Nov 28 06:56 native-platform2953326984648443135dir
drwxrwxr-x 2 rob rob  4096 Dec  8 18:03 native-platform5404575141685110828dir
drwxrwxr-x 2 rob rob  4096 Dec  5 13:28 native-platform5488604906885341235dir
drwxrwxr-x 2 rob rob  4096 Dec  9 09:29 native-platform5969166866748048826dir
drwxrwxr-x 2 rob rob  4096 Dec  9 20:25 native-platform6032919435567587484dir
drwxrwxr-x 2 rob rob  4096 Dec  2 07:16 native-platform800088999941561401dir
```

Comment: Did you fix it? I have the same issue here and it is driving me crazy.

Comment: Y. Get oracle jdk just for the IDE.

Comment: I have it. My issue is narrowed down to Genymotion acting crazy.

Comment: I only use Oracle's in Linux and editor freezes constantly so I have to force kill the whole process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OpenJDK, switch to Oracle JRE. Put it somewhere and set STUDIO_JDK to point to it.